# Looking for a tabbed sticky notes program

Tags: windows-7, note-taking

All sticky notes programs clutter the desktop. Want a tabbed one and freeware possibly. Googled a lot, couldn't find one that would let me create any number of tabs. Best example would be the in built sticky notes in Windows 7 but tabbed. Found one close called [NotesHolder](http://notes.aklabs.com/) but its not freeware.

Answer (score 1):

the closest I can think of is Microsoft OneNote Here is the linke https://www.onenote.com/

I've used it for my work and what's nice about it is that you can screenshot of it and it will save it to your OneNote folder. So, if you forgot and you can open it again it just saves it for you later. But I dont know if this is what you are looking for.

You can google on it but here is one you might want to check it out

http://office.about.com/od/MicrosoftOffice/tp/Easy-Steps-for-How-to-Use-Microsoft-Onenote.htm

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest

https://evernote.com/

This is a cool program that lets you access notes any where, iphone, ipad, windows, any browser.

It lets you store by books, pages, parahgraphs.

Comment: It is not a *sticky notes* program. The OP still wants one or a few 'stickies' on his/her screen.